# Can we provision SSL certificate for Internal Load Balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service, google-kubernetes-engine

I have deployed a basic application in GKE with
`service type = Internal Load balancer`
For this, it gives us an `HTTP` Endpoint
is there any way we can provision a certificate for it I need to convert it to an `HTTPS` endpoint

Also, I have tried exposing the application via Ingress but I do not want to expose the deployment to the outside world and need to keep it internally to the GCP

Any help will be very much appreciated

Comment: It depends how you're accessing it I suspect. Why do you need to? If it's internal, why make it HTTPS?

Comment: So I need to use cloud tasks which accept only https endpoint so I need to make as i don't want to expose the deployment via ingress is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You have **Two** options to do that

Go with **Service** that you have created or **Ingress internal**

**Internal LoadBalancer Service**

You have already created the service with LB, i tried but didn't find the **SSL** annotation to attach the **SSL cert** directly to the **K8s service** basically you can do this in **AWS**.

Attach cert to **GKE** LoadBalancer from **console**, you can use custom cert or **GCP** managed cert (i guess **GCP certificate manager** not support **HTTPS** for **internal LB** but you can upload to it).

Internal DNS name : https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/dns-names

**Ingress/Gateway**

If you have any internal pointing ingress controller then it will work looks like you might tried but Ingress controller which is Public.

**Internal Ingress** controller is backed by the **Internal LoadBalancer**, you can attach certs to it as normal ingress same way with **Annotation** or **secret**.

You can use **multiple** ingress option in case not having an idea, one **Public** and another **private**.

[Cert-manager](https://cert-manager.io/docs/) also could be easy option for generating certificates internally with ingress/gateway & use.

**White list Internal IP**

Incase if you have exposed service with Public LoadBalancer you can use below to whitelist traffic sources

```
loadBalancerSourceRanges:
      - 10.0.30.0/24
```

Comment: Still I am not clear on how we can achieve it because what i read was rn only we can provision certificate only for external facing LB not for internal TCP Lb